# Vaadin constructor with Autowired Spring JPA beans

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

I have a Spring Boot application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TaxApplication {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TaxApplication.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(TaxApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

I've set it up with Spring JPA for data access

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
```

I've set up a JPA Repository for the Account table:

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

    List<Account> findByNameStartsWithIgnoreCase(String name);
}
```

In my MainView, the `AccountRepository` doesn't get `@Autowired` by the Spring framework,

I can get an instance of it by Constructor injection:

```
public MainView(AccountRepository accountRepository) {
}
```

BUT If I try to use Autowiring the Constructor outputs 'null'

```
@Route
@Configurable
@PageTitle("Basic App Layout")
@CssImport(value = "combobox-styles.css", themeFor="vaadin-combo-box-overlay")
public class MainView extends AppLayout {
    
    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;
    
    public MainView() {
        
        System.out.println(accountRepository);
    }
}
```

Is this because the code is called from the MainView Constructor?  How can we use **Autowired** JPA beans with Vaadin?

**EDIT:**
I have added @EnableJpaRepositories to the Application, but Autowiring still fails

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"org.mypackage.tax.repo"})
public class TaxApplication {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just how autowiring in Spring works.

When you're using constructor injection, you can leave out the `@Autowired` annotation as long as there's just one constructor, but it's still autowired.

When you're using fields or setters, the dependencies will be injected after the bean has been constructed. This is unrelated to Vaadin.

Constructor injection is generally preferred over field injection. It makes the class easier to test, since you can easily pass mocks or stubs to the constructor when you instantiate it yourself.

Comment: Could also be mentioned that one can use a `@PostConstruct` method in place of the constructor when using field injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation to your `TaxApplication` class

Answer (score 0):

add this to your application **TaxApplication**:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages= {"com.tax.persistence"})
```

`com.tax.persistence` is the package that contains your repositories.

Also you can annotate **MainView** with `@Component` to make it Spring bean.

Comment: doesn't the `@Route` annotation already make the View a Spring bean?  i.e.  @Route is a @Component

Comment: I don't know the '@Route' annotation, in that case no need for '@Component' just scan for your repositories